# Plot 2D points on Wolfram Alpha

Tags: coordinates, lattice, wolframalpha

I'm trying to plot some 2d points with WA, but with no luck.

I do not want to plot points from data, like `[{1,2}, {3,4}, ...]` as described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PlottingListsOfData.html); what i would like to do is to plot points from a function/equation, e.g: `(x,y) : y=x`, "Every `x` and `y` that match `y=x`".

Of course my example is just a cointinuous straight line, obviously i'm trying to plot a discrete set of points; in fact i would like to plot a lattice of points from a formula describing those points.

Maybe i'm writing my formula wrong, maybe i need to use some specific WA function, maybe WA don't do that, i don't know, but i can't find any tips/clues about it.